# How do I use a .env api key in a controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I have keys from twilio API in my .env file that I am looking to use in one of my controller actions. Does anyone know how to access those .env keys in a controller method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in documentation of gem I assume you're using (https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) this vars can be found as a keys in constant hash `ENV`. F.e. `ENV['S3_BUCKET']`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use the `ENV` hash as stated by @Esse but I would personally avoid using ENV vars in my controller. Instead I would prefer to use it in the `Twillio.config` block in an initializer if you are using the [twillio gem](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby) or call it inside an adapter for the Twillio api if you're not using the gem(although not a bad idea even with the gem)